# I seem to be able to get my array on an html table but now i need to loop through and change the background colour of the answer in HTML?

Tags: javascript

I'm supposed to take this array and put it onto an HTML table. I seem to be able to do that. Now I need to loop through the array and change the background of the row that matches the age.

I'm able to get the table to display until I put in a loop.
Use a while loop with a counter to loop through the arrays. When you find the array position you belong to (today minus your birth year is equal to the age in the array) you should store the value of the grade text in that position. The loop should exit as soon as this value is found.
Remove the code to output text. Instead use getElementById to find the table row matching your grade and change the background color to #90EE90

This is what the outcome is supposed to be

[image]

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var data = [
        [6, 'Grade 1'],
        [7, 'Grade 2'],
        [8, 'Grade 3'],
        [9, 'Grade 4'],
        [10, 'Grade 5'],
        [11, 'Grade 6'],
      ];

      // Draw HTML table
      var perrow = 1, // 3 cells per row
        html = "<table><tr>";

      // Loop through array and add table cells
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>";
        // Break into next row
        var next = i + 1;
        if (next % perrow == 0 && next != data.length) {
          html += "</tr><tr>";
        }
      }
      html += "</tr></table>";

      let yourGrade = grade.find(e => {
          return e[0] == age;

          function changecolors() {
            var a1 = document.getElementById("gradeTable");
            var a1Legnth = a1.legnth;
            for (var i = 0; i < a1Legnth; i++) {
              a1[i].style.background = "#aaabba";
            }
          });

        // Attach HTML to container
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
      });
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Javascript array to table
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- ALL YOU NEED IS A CONTAINER -->
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The JavaScript has unbalanced brackets.

Comment: How do I balance brackets?

Comment: You're missing the closing `})` for the `grade.find` call.

Comment: And you never use the `yourGrade` variable that you set there. Maybe you left out some lines when you were copying the code?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a 2-dimensional array. You need nested loops to create the corresponding table. Each element of `data` is a row, each element of `data[i]` is a cell.

```
var html = "<table>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  html += "<tr>";
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    html += "<td>" + data[i][j] + "</td>";
  }
  html += "</tr>";
}
html += "</table>";
```